# Change UITableView header tint color

Tags: xcode, uitableview, header, tint

I have implemented the following code in order to change the **tint** of the section headers in a tableView. I just want to change the color tint, not to apply a view from my own. The app, however, seems to ignore it and the sections headers keep being displayed with the default gray. Any clue about what could I be doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [[tableView headerViewForSection:section] setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    return [tableView headerViewForSection:section];
}
```

Comment: Please google it ... Sure u will  get answer @Álvaro Morales Navarro

Comment: see this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813068/uitableview-change-section-header-color @Álvaro Morales Navarro

Comment: Thanks Babul, I definitely googled it for days. The solution is not using the setTintColor method, so it's not what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help anyways. :-)

Comment: Thanks again! I finally found what I was looking for in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294876/changing-the-color-of-uitableview-section-headers

Answer (score 2):

this is work 100% and you can change your index or header text color

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // if you have index/header text in your tableview change your index text color 
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerIndexText = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [headerIndexText.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}
```