# Change the Header in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image: Main Image]

Do you know the name of the part where "california" is written, and how i can change its background color and textcolor ?

Thanks, Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to edit a `UITableView` header, you have to make use of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

[Check out an example from another Stack Overflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813068/uitableview-change-section-header-color).

Comment: thanks, I was not sure of the name. I thought the header was the opposite of the footer, above the tableview.

Comment: is there not an easier way to change nothing but the text and the background color ?

Comment: Unfortunately a `UITableView` header is not very easily customizable - the only way to change it is to create the view on your own in a `UITableViewDelegate`.