# How could we make the section header touchable in UITable?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I wanna make it like, touch the section header then jump to end of this section. How could I do it? Any suggestions? Cheers

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7]];
    UILabel *titleInSection = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width/3, 20)] autorelease];
    [titleInSection setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0]];
    [titleInSection setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    if (isSectionLoad == YES){
        [categoryData retain];
        titleInSection.text = [categoryData objectAtIndex:section];
    }

    titleInSection.tag = section;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:)];
    [titleInSection addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];

    [headerView addSubview:titleInSection];
    return headerView;
}

- (IBAction)sectionTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    switch (recognizer.view.tag) {
        case 0:
            // do what you want for section with index 0
            NSLog(@"HELLO WORLD!!!");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that 0 is the default value for the tag property. I suggest adding a constant offset.

Comment: As Nekto said, Add recognizer to headerView, and set property headerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; Because in my code, i added the action trigger to label, but it should in section header's view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement method `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` in your delegate. In this method create `UIView` with needful subviews (labels, images and etc.). At the end just add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to that view. And then return it it.

For example:

```
- (IBAction)sectionTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    switch (recognizer.view.tag) {
        case 0:
            // do what you want for section with index 0
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *label;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", section];
    label.tag = section;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:)];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    return  label;
}
```

Comment: hi Nekto, thx for your helps. I've tried this, but it seems nothing happened when i touched section header. I implement NSLog(@"Hello!"); in case 0 for testing, and it doesn't print out on console when i touch it. BTW, in "- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section "  should it return to an UIView?

Comment: Yes, it should return UIView. Post your code of that function.

Comment: Add `recognizer` to `headerView`, and set property `headerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: it works, thank you very much. btw, could you have a look " UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)]; "  If I change to "UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 60)]"  the height of section header does not change. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, you should return height in method named smth like this `heightOfSection`. Try to search in docs, im writing now from iphone..

Comment: "- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;"  thx mate

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but there's a newer better answer to this question:

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173639/2371425

tl;dr - iOS6 gave us these new methods for changing the attributes of section headers/footers.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view 
    forSection:(NSInteger)

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view 
    forSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Use these methods to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the headerView.

Ex.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:)];

    [view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

}
- (IBAction)sectionTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
 NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```