# Change the sections header background color in UITableView using an array of headers

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a array of headers that I use

```
let sectionHeaderTitleArray = ["test1","test2","test3]
```

and they are showed using

```
func tableView[tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
return self.sectionHeaderTitleArray[section] as String
}
```

Now all of this works fine but I would like to modify the background color of the headers so that they are more visible (Darker Color)

any idea if I can do this in a simple line or do I need to use a custom cell to create this

thanks

update

```
  //number of sections and names for the table

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.sectionHeaderTitleArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.sectionHeaderTitleArray[section] as String
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, ViewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView - change section header color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813068/uitableview-change-section-header-color)

Comment: well you are returning a UIColor when it expects a UIView..

Comment: you need to set it with returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor() where returnedView is the UIView you initialize in func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?

Comment: thanks this changes the color correctly but my width and length settings are all setup in interface builder with autolayout.. how can I get this to adapt to the screen size?

Comment: You will have to manually calculate the y value based on the data you are using, the x value can be 0, the width value will be UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width and the height will be around 10.0 (play around with this to your liking)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of using the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
```

data source method, you can use the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

delegate method and simply customize the `UIView` returned as you wish.

For example set the text of the `UILabel` `textLabel` to your desired value and the `backgroundColor` to the desired `UIColor`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)) //set these values as necessary
    returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(labelX, labelY, labelWidth, labelHeight))
    label.text = self.sectionHeaderTitleArray[section]
    returnedView.addSubview(label)

    return returnedView
}
```

**SWIFT 5**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)) //set these values as necessary
            returnedView.backgroundColor = .white

            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))

            label.text = self.sectionHeaderTitleArray[section]
            returnedView.addSubview(label)

            return returnedView
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but i can use my array of sections title in this

Comment: So set the textLabel.text property to the desired section title as I suggested :)

Comment: I need all my sections to have the same lightgreycolor

Comment: So set the backgroundColor to the desired UIColor (lightGrey in your case)

Comment: can you please post the code you have tried that isnt working

Comment: Setting background color directly to header view raises runtime warning `Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead.`

Comment: Thanks @brigadir, his code is what is missing from that answer above.

Answer (score 129):

If you're using only titleForHeaderInSection :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Comment: I get a SIGABORT: Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1b6464bc0) to 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView'

Comment: Hi, cdub. I've just tested it and it still works. Maybe you're returning some other view in viewForHeaderInSection callback? Anyway, you can insert - guard view is UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { print(view); return } check before setting color to see what's going on.

Comment: This works fine, but please do not force unwrap. You do not need to do that here at all. It just makes your code more prone to errors.

Answer (score 17):

You have to keep both

> titleForHeaderInSection

AND

> viewForHeaderInSection

Here is some working code in **Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sectionHeaderTitleArray[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    returnedView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 7, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    label.text = self.sectionHeaderTitleArray[section]
    label.textColor = .black
    returnedView.addSubview(label)

    return returnedView
}
```

Answer (score 17):

**SWIFT 5**

```swift
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerId") as! CustomHeader
    let background = UIView(frame: view.bounds, background: .clear)
    header.backgroundView = background
    return header
}
```

---

**SWIFT 4**

Super easy, by setting header's view, contentView background color..

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerId") as! CustomHeader
   header.contentView.backgroundColor = AnyColor
   return header
}
```

Comment: This answer is a bit incomplete but seems to be the correct method. How would I go about creating the custom header view with a unique id in the first place? Currently I've seen a lot of methods online that just use a custom created cell that returns the content view of that cell. Would it be possible for you to expand a bit?

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926612/swift-how-creating-custom-viewforheaderinsection-using-a-xib-file to fill in the blanks

Comment: I find this answer by far the cleanest.

Answer (score 16):

Swift **5** **iOS 13**:

```
//Remove 'override' if you don't override from UITableviewController
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    guard let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
    headerView.tintColor = .clear //use any color you want here .red, .black etc
}
```

Comment: Just providing code with no explanation is not helpful. I can't see what this adds that is not covered in the accepted answer.

Comment: You can check documentation for more or I can suggest you some books what do you think? Let me know I can do it :)

Comment: @Dragonthoughts is wrong, tintColor is the puzzle piece i was missing. This is the correct answer. Thanks Adriatik!

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4.X**

This is tested and working code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Total Count (41)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
}
```

Comment: Hey, using tintColor background changed how? 
Nice solution I tried using backgroundview.backgroundColor but it did not work thanks!

Comment: Thanks mate! Setting tintColor worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3+**

I used this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 20))
    headerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = stringValues[section]
    headerView.addSubview(label)
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    return headerView

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    guard let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }

    headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

And, if you want different header background (and/or text) colors for each section:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    guard let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }

    switch section {

    case 0:
        headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red
        headerView.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    case 1:
        headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .green
        headerView.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    case 2:
        headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .yellow
        headerView.textLabel?.textColor = .black

        // etc

    default:
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift5**

*Versión updated to **iOS 11,12,13,14** with example*

change background color and text color:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    guard let tableView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
    tableView.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    tableView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Full example of viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    private let array: [String] = ["ab","bc","cd","de","ef","fg","gh","hi","ij","jk"]
    let sectionHeaderTitleArray = ["test1","test2", "test3"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {}
        else {
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        }
        configTableview()
    }
    
    private func configTableview() {
        tableView.registerCell(type: SyncCell.self)
        tableView.separatorColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3066673801, blue: 1, alpha: 0.19)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        guard let tableView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
        tableView.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        tableView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionHeaderTitleArray[section]
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 130
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected cell: \(indexPath)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = array[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(type: SyncCell.self, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.configCell(text: item)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Background color not changing any suggestion for label it's working?

Comment: What is your iOS version?

Comment: Versión updated to iOS 11,12,13,14 with example

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `titleForHeaderInSection`, then the easiest way is to add in viewDidLoad():

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

For some reason, setting ClearColor for Background in the View section for the TableView in the Interface Builder doesnt always set it to transparent. But adding this one line in the code (for me at least) does.

Answer (score 1):

override viewForHeaderInSection and create UITableViewHeaderFooterView

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var headrview = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "aaa")
    if headrview == nil {
        headrview = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(reuseIdentifier: "aaa")
    }
    let bview = UIView()
    bview.backgroundColor = Theme.current.navigationColor
    headrview?.backgroundView = bview
    headrview?.textLabel?.textColor = Theme.current.primaryTextColor
    return headrview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 solution.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView:UIView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
   return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom header view, you can do it with `contentView.backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use hacks such as willDisplayHeaderView method or others.
Simply create your own class of UITableViewHeaderFooterView.
Then in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` return your created custom header view. You should change background color not directly for your header view but for contentView of your header view

```
let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: NotificationSettingsHeaderView.reuseIdentifier) as! NotificationSettingsHeaderView
headerView.label.text = dataSource.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[section].title
headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
return headerView
```

What's even better is to setup background color in `init` of your header view subclass

Answer (score 0):

For default header view of UITableView

```
tableView.headerView(forSection: 0)?.tintColor = .clear
```

Answer (score -1):

This will change it for all the headers in your application :

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().backgroundColor = theme.subViewBackgroundColor
```

Answer (score -1):

override or implement the function `tableview will display`

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let headerView = (view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView)
        headerView?.tintColor = .clear
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

We can change the footer color in a section of tableView using the below code snippet.

1. call the Method heightForFooterInSection

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
           return 5.0
       }
2. call the method viewForFooterInSection

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
       let viw = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 5))
       viw.backgroundColor = .white
       return viw
   }

Hope this will help you. This is a tested Code.

Comment: Height should be equal in both methods

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be great if you can format the code part with the SO's inbuild code formatting tool.

Comment: next time I will  @KarthickRamesh